# Advantages of CFNetwork over BSD sockets & GCD on iOS and MacOS?

Tags: sockets, grand-central-dispatch, cfnetwork

I'm building a Mac application that communicates with iOS (devices and simulators).  It is intended to just use Wifi networking (for devices in range of the Mac's network) or the loopback/link local devices when used with the simulator. It should never use 3G/LTE networking but VPN connections linking the iOS device to their network over wifi might be useful to some users.

Is there any advantage in using CFNetwork/CFRunloop/CFStream based sockets over just "going to the metal" with BSD sockets (in combination with GCD & dispatch_io)?

It seems to me that CFNetworking is just adding an unnecessary abstraction on top of BSD sockets if I'm going to use GCD, dispatch I/O, and dispatch sources rather than CFNetwork/CFRunLoop based data read/write events.

The network protocol will be a custom binary protocol. I.e., not based on HTTP or any other existing protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need cellular or VPN-on-demand, then I can't really think of a reason you'd **have** to use CFNetwork, but a wise man once told me: "Use the highest level abstraction that gets the job done." CFNetwork is a higher level API than BSD sockets, and GCD `dispatch_io`.

On the other hand, "Go with what ya know." If you're more comfortable working in the BSD sockets or GCD `dispatch_io` idioms, by all means, go forth and prosper.